# While loop adding extra [] on every step

Tags: python, numeric, newtons-method

I have defined the function newton to be the implementation of the Newton method to find roots of real-valued and vector-valued functions.

The problem is that, the sequence created is being included into an extra [] at every step.

Why is this happening and how can I avoid it by making changes on the newton function definition?

This is my output sequence:

```
x_1 = [[4.66097544]]
x_2 = [[[2.76124695]]]
x_3 = [[[[3.14624513]]]]
x_4 = [[[[[3.14159265]]]]]
```

This is my code:

```
from math import exp
import numpy as np
from numpy import array
from numpy.linalg import norm
from numpy import sin,cos,pi

def newton (F, DF, x0, eps, K):
    x = x0 - np.linalg.inv(DF(x0))*F(x0)
    k=1
    print("x_", end="")
    print(k, end="")
    print(" = ", end="")
    print(x)
    print("( ||F(x)|| = ", end="")
    print(norm(F(x)), end=" )\n")
    while (norm(F(x)) > eps) and (k<=K):
        x = x - np.linalg.inv(DF(x))*F(x)
        k += 1
        print("x_", end="")
        print(k, end="")
        print(" = ", end="")
        print(x)
        print("( ||F(x)|| = ", end="")
        print(norm(F(x)), end=" )\n")
    return x,k

F = lambda y: cos(y/2)
DF = lambda y: array([-sin(y/2)/2])
x,k = newton(F, DF, array([1.]), 1e-8, 100)
```

Any help or comments are highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This would have to be a result of calling `norm(F(x))` or `np.linalg.inv(DF(x))*F(x)`. Feed each some sample data, see which is causing the extra nesting (adding another dimension to the data), then read the docs and see why it's doing that (or read the docs for each function first).

Comment: `x = x - (np.linalg.inv(DF(x))*F(x)).reshape((1,1))`

Comment: You can use `f-string` to print output in a more readable manner instead of series of `print` statements

Comment: Wouldn't that make my implementation useless for a vector valued function F? @Epsi95

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that DF function, that always return the argument into a array. So you are passing arrays and it will return that array inside another array. If i understood your code, you can drop that array for the DF function and the linalg.inv call, and just manipulate your lambda functions to accept arguments from a array:

See if this do what you want:

```
from math import exp
import numpy as np
from numpy import array
from numpy.linalg import norm
from numpy import sin,cos,pi

def newton (F, DF, x0, eps, K):
    x = x0 - F(x0)/DF(x0)
    k=1
    print("x_", end="")
    print(k, end="")
    print(" = ", end="")
    print(x)
    print("( ||F(x)|| = ", end="")
    print(norm(F(x)), end=" )\n")
    while (norm(F(x)) > eps) and (k<=K):
        x = x - DF(x)*F(x)
        k += 1
        print("x_", end="")
        print(k, end="")
        print(" = ", end="")
        print(x)
        print("( ||F(x)|| = ", end="")
        print(norm(F(x)), end=" )\n")
    return x,k

F = lambda y: cos(y[0]/2)
DF = lambda y: -sin(y[0]/2)/2 
x,k = newton(F, DF, array([1]), 1e-8, 100)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "q2.py", line 35, in <module>
    x,k = newton(F, DF, array([1.]), 1e-8, 100)
  File "q2.py", line 8, in newton
    x = x0 - np.linalg.inv(DF(x0))*F(x0)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in inv
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 540, in inv
    _assert_stacked_2d(a)

Comment: File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 197, in _assert_stacked_2d
    raise LinAlgError('%d-dimensional array given. Array must be '
numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: 1-dimensional array given. Array must be at least two-dimensional

Comment: For some reason the DF argument has to be an array. I am supposed to do the newton implementation while the x,k = newton(...) is the part given to me to test my implementation.

Comment: In my sugestion i removed that np.linalg.inv also.

Comment: And i think it should be F/DF and not F*DF?